# Applying removeObjectAtIndex has different scope to appendString in mutably copied array

Tags: objective-c

Copying an NSMutableArray using mutableCopy apparently creates a physical new copy of the array. The evidence of this is that removal of an element from the copy using removeObjectAtIndex does not remove the element from the original. However if an element in the copy is changed, the element in the original is also changed. This is about as intuitive as a photon of light being both a particle and a wave and I do not understand it. Please can someone explain this to me.

Code follows.

```
NSMutableArray *dataArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:
                                 [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"one"],
                                 [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"two"],
                                 [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"three"],
                                 [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"four"],
                                 nil];
    NSMutableArray *dataArray2;
    NSMutableString *mstr;
    dataArray2 = [dataArray mutableCopy];
    [dataArray2 removeObjectAtIndex:0];
    mstr    = [dataArray2 objectAtIndex:0];
    [mstr appendString:@"ONE"];
    NSLog(@"Data Array: ");
    for (NSString *elem in dataArray) {
        NSLog(@"%@",elem);
    }
    NSLog(@"Data Array2: ");
    for (NSString *elem in dataArray2) {
        NSLog(@"%@",elem);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `mutableCopy` method creates a [*shallow copy*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_copy#Shallow_copy) of the array, meaning that references to elements of the original array are copied to the new instance of `NSMutableArray` returned by `mutableCopy`. That is why manipulating (adding/removing elements) the copy of the array does not alter the composition of the original array, while changes to *elements* of the array that allow mutation become "visible" through both copies of the array.

Comment: Ah, so the copy is just an array of references to the elements in the original array. You can delete a reference from the copy, but amending an element changes both the original and copy because there is only one real array.

Answer (score 0):

It's a question of whether you're changing the array object or one of the objects it references.

Pretend that in the non-computer world you have lists of people's names on two different pieces of paper.  If you scratch out the name from one list, it has no effect on the other.  If, instead, you give one of those people a cup of coffee, the person has it whether you look them up on list A or list B.  :-)